# Difficulty trying to take the n-th root of a product of n numbers

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a recursive function which takes in a list of n numbers. What this function should do is take the product of the n numbers and then take the nth root. I got the product of the n numbers working but do not know how to implement the nth root.

What I tried doing is implementing the ***expt x y*** function but could not get it right in the [recursion](/questions/tagged/recursion). Moreover, when trying to implement this function, I also don't know how I will be able to feed the expt function the nth root. ***(y=1/n)***.

```
(define (nth-root-of-product-of-numbers lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) 1]
        [else (* (first lst) (nth-root-of-product-of-numbers (rest lst)))]))
```

So, the above code produces the product on the list of n-numbers correctly, however it does not compensate for the n-th root problem. A sample input would be:

```
(check-within
(nth-root-of-product-of-numbers (cons 9 (cons 14 (cons 2 empty)))) 6.316359598 0.0001)
```

Comment: Please edit the question with a sample input and the expected output.

Comment: Ok. I have edited in a sample input and the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the nth-root at the end of the recursion. There are several ways to do this - for example, defining a helper procedure for finding the product and taking the root after calculating it:

```
(define (nth-root-of-product-of-numbers lst)
  (define (product lst)
    (cond [(empty? lst) 1]
          [else (* (first lst) (product (rest lst)))]))
  (expt (product lst) (/ 1 (length lst))))
```

A more efficient solution would be to write a tail-recursive procedure, and to pass along the number of elements to avoid calculating the `length` at the end. Here's how, using a [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29):

```
(define (nth-root-of-product-of-numbers lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (acc 1) (n 0))
    (cond [(empty? lst)
           (expt acc (/ 1 n))]
          [else
           (loop (rest lst) (* (first lst) acc) (add1 n))])))
```

An even more idiomatic solution would be to use built-in procedures to calculate the product:

```
(define (nth-root-of-product-of-numbers lst)
  (expt (apply * lst) (/ 1 (length lst))))
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(nth-root-of-product-of-numbers (list 9 14 2))
=> 6.316359597656378
```